# How to add more objects to my form without adding the same amount of code

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, duplication

I have been making a small game for fun. In the game you are a small spaceship(an image) that shoots lazer beams(shape) at an object(panel). At this moment u can only fire one lazer beam at a time because there is only one lazer beam(shape) and there is only one object(panel) to shoot. So with the coding I have I would like to know how I can add more lazer beams and objects but especially lazer beams because I don't want to repeat the procedures for each lazer beam and for each panel.

Here is the code.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, jpeg;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    Button1: TButton;
    Shape1: TShape;
    Timer3: TTimer;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
   procedure StartPanelAnimation1;
   procedure DoPanelAnimationStep1;
   function  PanelAnimationComplete1: Boolean;
   procedure Startlazeranimation1;
   procedure DolazeranimationStep1;
   { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
 var key : char;
{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }



{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.DoPanelAnimationStep1;
begin
Panel1.Top := Panel1.Top+1;
end;

function TForm1.PanelAnimationComplete1: Boolean;
begin
 Result := Panel1.Top=512;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartPanelAnimation1;
begin
  Panel1.Top := 0;
  Timer1.Interval := 1;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DoPanelAnimationStep1;
  if PanelAnimationComplete1 then
    StartPanelAnimation1;
   if (shape1.Top < panel1.Top) and (shape1.Left < panel1.Left+104) and (shape1.Left > panel1.Left)   then
   begin
    startpanelanimation1;
   sleep(10);
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 button1.Hide;
  key := 'a';
  timer2.Enabled := true;
  StartPanelAnimation1; 
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 shape1.Visible := false;
 timer3.Enabled := false;
 timer2.Enabled := false;
 end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
   begin
image1.Left := image1.Left-10;
end;

 procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    begin
  image1.Left := image1.Left+10;
end;

procedure TForm1.DolazeranimationStep1;
begin
 shape1.Top := shape1.Top-10;
end;


 procedure TForm1.Startlazeranimation1;
 begin
 shape1.Top := image1.Top;
 shape1.Left := image1.Left+55;
 shape1.Visible := true;
  Timer3.Interval := 1;
  Timer3.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
var k : integer;
begin
 DolazeranimationStep1;
  if (shape1.Top < panel1.Top) and (shape1.Left < panel1.Left+104) and (shape1.Left > panel1.Left) or         (shape1.Top=clientheight) then
   begin
    timer3.Enabled := false;
    shape1.Visible := false;
    for k := 1 to 5 do
    sleep(1);
    begin
    application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
    shape1.Top := 0;
    shape1.Left := 0;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
 shape1.Show;
 startlazeranimation1;
end;

end.
```

(The above is the old code)

I have successfully done what Stijn Sanders suggested. But now in this if

```
 if (Shape1.top < panel1.Top) and (shape1.Left < panel1.Left+104) and (shape1.Left > panel1.Left)   then
```

never tests true because shape1 never passes panel1 it, only the shape created on on click passes the panel.

So is there another way to test if the shape is at the pnael.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all components need to be created at design time. At run-time, for example using a TTimer and its event, you can call `TShape.Create(Self);` to have an extra shape. Keep the reference to the resulting value somewhere convenient, for example a (dynamic) array, and remember to set `MyShape.Parent:=Self;` or `MyShape.Parent:=Panel1;` so the system knows when and where to display this new control.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

const
  MaxRays=100;
  RayStep=8;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Rays:array[0..MaxRays-1] of TShape;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to MaxRays-1 do Rays[i]:=nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  i:=0;
  while (i<MaxRays) and (Rays[i]<>nil) do inc(i);
  if i<MaxRays then
   begin
    Rays[i]:=TShape.Create(Self);
    Rays[i].Shape:=stEllipse;
    Rays[i].Pen.Color:=clRed;
    Rays[i].Pen.Style:=psSolid;
    Rays[i].Brush.Color:=clYellow;
    Rays[i].Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
    Rays[i].SetBounds(X-4,Y-20,9,41);
    Rays[i].Parent:=Self;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to MaxRays-1 do
    if Rays[i]<>nil then
    begin
      Rays[i].Top:=Rays[i].Top-RayStep;
      if Rays[i].Top<0 then FreeAndNil(Rays[i]);
    end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: sorry but I dont understand what you are saying.

Comment: I tried it but I'm still confused on what to do. All the rays and MaxRays and RayStep confuse me please help. P.S. I'm sure it will work I'm not saying the code is wrong.

Comment: I'm doing something similar like your code, you animate a panel with a TTimer, I animate an array of TShape's with a TTimer. A new TShape is created and added to the array when you click the form. Just read the code slowly and see if you understand what it does.

Comment: It works!!! I forgot to put the 
    const
      MaxRays=100;
      RayStep=8;
in. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: From the code, I can't know where Shape1 and Panel1 are. If you set `Shape1.Parent:=Panel1` the Top and Left will be relative to the space whithin the panel.

Comment: The idea is that you must shoot the panel. So the panel will be set to a random location at the top of the screen then move down to the botom of the screen. You must shoot the panel before it reaches the botom but I dont know how to test if the created shape is at the location of the panel to reset the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Create your objects dynamically at runtime and keep track of them in a list, then you can loop through the list when needed, eg:

```
unit Unit1; 

interface 

uses 
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, 
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, jpeg; 

type 
  TForm1 = class(TForm) 
    PanelTimer: TTimer; 
    Button1: TButton; 
    LazerTimer: TTimer; 
    Image1: TImage; 
    procedure PanelTimerTimer(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; 
      MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean); 
    procedure FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; 
      MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean); 
    procedure LazerTimerTimer(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; 
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); 
  private 
    { Private declarations } 
    Lazers: TList; 
    Panels: TList; 
    procedure StartPanelAnimation;
    procedure StartLazerAnimation; 
  public
    { Public declarations } 
  end; 

var 
  Form1: TForm1; 

implementation 

{$R *.dfm} 

{ TForm1 } 

procedure TForm1.StartPanelAnimation; 
var
  Panel: TPanel;
begin 
  Panel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel.Parent := Self;
  Panel.Top := 0;
  // set other Panel properties as needed... 
  Panel.Visible := True; 
  Panels.Add(Panel);
  if not PanelTimer.Enabled then
  begin
    PanelTimer.Interval := 1; 
    PanelTimer.Enabled := True; 
  end;
end; 

procedure TForm1.PanelTimerTimer(Sender: TObject); 
var
  k: Integer;
  Panel: TPanel;
begin 
  for k := 0 to Panels.Count-1 do
  begin
    Panel := TPanel(Panels[k]);
    Panel.Top := Panel.Top + 1; 
    if Panel.Top = 512 then 
      Panel.Top := 0;
  end;
end; 

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  StartPanelAnimation1;  
end; 

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  Lazers := TList.Create;
  Panels := TList.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  Lazers.Free;
  Panels.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  PanelTimer.Enabled := False; 
  LazerTimer.Enabled := False; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; 
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean); 
begin 
  Image1.Left := Image1.Left - 10; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; 
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean); 
begin 
  Image1.Left := Image1.Left + 10; 
end; 

procedure TForm1.StartLazerAnimation; 
var
  Lazer: TShape;
begin 
  Lazer := TShape.Create(Self);
  Lazer.Parent := Self;
  // set Lazer properties as needed...
  Lazer.Top := Image1.Top; 
  Lazer.Left := Image1.Left + 55; 
  Lazer.Visible := True; 
  Lazers.Add(Lazer);
  if not Lazer.Enabled then
  begin
    Lazer.Interval := 1; 
    Lazer.Enabled := True; 
  end;
end; 

procedure TForm1.LazerTimerTimer(Sender: TObject); 
var
  k, m : integer;
  Lazer: TShape;
  Panel: TPanel;
  PanelHit: Boolean; 
begin 
  k := 0;
  while k < Lazers.Count do
  begin
    Lazer := TShape(Lazers[k]);
    Lazer.Top := Lazer.Top - 10; 
    for m := 0 to Panels.Count-1 do
    begin        
      Panel := TPanel(Panels[m]);
      PanelHit := (Lazer.Top > (Panel.Top+Panel.Height)) and (Lazer.Left > Panel.Left) and (Lazer.Left < (Panel.Left+Panel.Width));
      if PanelHit then
      begin
        Panels.Remove(Panel);
        Panel.Free;
        if Panels.Count = 0 then
          PanelTimer.Enabled := False;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    if PanelHit or (Lazer.Top = 0) then 
    begin 
      Lazers.Remove(Lazer);
      Lazer.Free;
      if Lazers.Count = 0 then
        LazerTimer.Enabled := False; 
    end else
      Inc(k); 
  end;
end; 

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; 
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); 
begin 
  StartLazerAnimation; 
end; 

end.
```